# Access2019で作成したaccdbファイルがAccess2016で開けない

Tags: ms-access

Office2019(32bit)のAccessで作成したデータベース(accdb)が、違うPCの2016のAccess(32bit)で開くことができず、下図のようなエラーが表示されます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

いろいろ調べてみましたが、本来これは2007でBigIntを扱うようにした時と出てくるのですが、
そもそも全然2007はからんでいません。
ましてや、作成したデータベース中には一つとしてBigIntは使用しておらず、なんで
こんな変なタイミングでこのエラーが出てくるのかさっぱり解りません。

図中にある『ここをクリック』の部分をクリックしても、表示されるのは前期のような2007の
問題で、まったく解決の糸口になっていません。

ファイルの破損も考えましたが、2019の入っている環境だと何の問題もなく開きます。
また、『閉じるときに最適化』をしてみても、これもダメ。

ちなみに、開けないのは一つだけで、そのほかの同じようなファイルは開けています。

原因と対策がお分かりになる方がいらっしゃいましたら、お教えいただけますでしょうか。

宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access に限らず、ツールのバージョンによって機能のサポート状況も異なるのでファイル形式も変わっている可能性があります。
Access 2016 のリリース時には 2019 なんてバージョンは存在しないため、エラーが出ているのではないでしょうか。

いったん 2019 側で古いファイル形式 (`*.mdb`) で保存してみるのはどうでしょうか？

**参考:**
[.accdb データベースを以前のファイル形式に変換する](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/-accdb-%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%83%99%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%82%92%E4%BB%A5%E5%89%8D%E3%81%AE%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E5%BD%A2%E5%BC%8F%E3%81%AB%E5%A4%89%E6%8F%9B%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B-59369336-6d58-4094-b396-ee5bb637717b)

Comment: いつもありがとうございます。ご指摘いただいた方法をもとに、一度mdbにしてみたところ、mdbでは開くことができるようになりました。ただ、その後再びmdbをaccdbに戻すことをせず、もう一度返還前のaccdbを開いてみると、なぜかそちらも開くようになっていました。mdbのほうはあくまでも別名で保存した別ファイルだったのに、もとからあった開けなかったはずのaccdbが開けるようになっていました。なんかすっきりしない解決ですが、今後も同じ事態が発生しないとも限りませんので、参考にさせて頂きたいと思います。ありがとうございました。今後ともよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

エラーが発生する　Access DBファイルは、Windows API を利用するようなモジュールが含まれているのではないでしょうか？その影響で、エラーが発生している可能性も考えられます。

[64 ビット版または 32 ビット版の Office を選択する](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/64-%E3%83%93%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E7%89%88%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9F%E3%81%AF-32-%E3%83%93%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E7%89%88%E3%81%AE-office-%E3%82%92%E9%81%B8%E6%8A%9E%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B-2dee7807-8f95-4d0c-b5fe-6c6f49b8d261?ui=ja-jp&rs=ja-jp&ad=jp#32or64Bit=%E6%96%B0%E3%81%97%E3%81%84%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3)

- Office2019の場合は、意図的に（～版を）指定しないと　Accessは 64bit 版になります。
- Office2016の場合は、意図的に（～版を）指定しないと　Accessは 32bit 版になります。

質問文には、"32ビット版"と記載されていますが、何かの原因で 64 bit版がインストールされていることも考えられます。

そこでまずは、インストールされているソフトウェアが期待した通り 32 bit がインストールされているか確認したほうが良いでしょう。

[使用している Office のバージョンを確認する方法](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B-office-%E3%81%AE%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%82%92%E7%A2%BA%E8%AA%8D%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95-932788b8-a3ce-44bf-bb09-e334518b8b19)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。開けなかったファイルには、一切コードの類は含まれていませんでした。APIどころか、通常のVBAのコードも含んでいない、行ってみればバックエンドとして使用するデータの塊だけだったのですが、どうやっても開けませんでした。アプリも32bitで統一しているので、そのあたりの互換性も問題なかったのですが…。そのあとで何とか開くようになりましたが、まったく違った方法でした。ありがとうございました。また何かありましたらご相談させてください。

Comment: そうですか。原因は別でしたか。でも開くようになってよかったですね。(^^)